# Android Studio unable to fetch packages from some default SDK update sites

Tags: android-studio

I just installed `Android Studio 1.5.1` on a `Windows 7 64bit` machine. I went to the built in SDK manager and I see that Android Studio is unable to fetch from some of the default sources. 
[image]

Now I have tried some solutions that I saw online such as ticking the `Force https:// sources to be fetched using http://`, using a `proxy`, etc. I tried them and it still doesn't fetch from the 5 sources above. I have already disabled my firewall and anti virus for what it's worth.

I also tried using the Standalone SDK manager and still wasn't able to fetch successfully from those 5 sources. Here's the log: 
[image]

I find it strange that I'm able fetch from the other default sources when ALL of the default sources are from `https://dl.google.com/android/....` anyway. I also tried opening the URLs on my browser and I can see the page load. I also tried pinging via `cmd` and I get replies from it.

Is the problem on Google's server side? Anyone else experiencing this currently? I did not face this issue on an installation I made 3 weeks ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to reload the sources again a day after and it now successfully retrieves the packages from the URL. I guess the problem was on Google's side after all. Hope this helps anyone who might encounter this issue in the future.